# Has anybody implemented server-side rendering for echarts with Coldfusion?

Tags: ajax, coldfusion, echarts, lucee

I'm hoping to get your thoughts on the following topic. I'm using echarts on my application to display charts. All has been going good with it, but I have stumbled on the situation where I need to render a chart on the server-side.

Echarts have posted a few examples here: https://echarts.apache.org/en/tutorial.html#Server-side%20Rendering. The server I'm developing on doesn't have the likes of nodejs installed and I don't imagine it will be available.

Basically, I'm asking have you implemented rendering echarts on the server with lucee/coldfusion? Which headless tool have you used to do so?

Would something like CFSelenium achieve this? https://github.com/teamcfadvance/CFSelenium

Thanks for any stories or examples you can share!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up installing NodeJs on my server and did the server side rendering that way. I called node with Shell script which was called with cfexecute.